# How to auto inject language by place pattern in PhpStorm for function?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

How to configure PhpStorm to automatically inject Bash inside `run(...)` function call? For example i want to inject bash here:

```
run("mv source dest && echo 'bash';");
```

This does not working:

```
+ phpLiteralExpression().withText("run")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following places pattern:

```
+ phpLiteralExpression().withSuperParent(2, phpFunctionReference().withText(string().startsWith("run(")))
```

Unfortunately there is no documentation for this feature, in fact the docs specifically warn:

> These rules are PhpStorm internals, and it is strongly recommended that you use the predefined injection configurations and avoid creating new ones.

So it is in practise necessary to look at the sources of IntelliJ IDEA. The classes of interest are [`com.intellij.patterns.PlatformPatterns`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/patterns/PlatformPatterns.java) and [`com.intellij.patterns.PsiElementPattern`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/core-api/src/com/intellij/patterns/PsiElementPattern.java) and their various superclasses.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. There i can find docs about places pattern?

Comment: Thanks! Some sort of public API will be helpful. This autoinjecting language feature looks cool.